# Adding OpenTok framework to my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, opentok

So I am trying to add the OpenTok framework to my code. I am downloading the IOS SDK from https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/ then I am dragging the opentok.framwork file into my list of frameworks. When I build my code it is failing with this error:

```
Ld /Users/hussein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocieteGeneral-hiagtpmptjkrqjbabjxpjmnshezi/Build/Intermediates/SocieteGeneral.build/Debug-iphoneos/SocieteGeneral.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SocieteGeneral normal arm64
cd /Users/hussein/Projects/ios-client
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/hussein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocieteGeneral-hiagtpmptjkrqjbabjxpjmnshezi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib -F/Users/hussein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocieteGeneral-hiagtpmptjkrqjbabjxpjmnshezi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/hussein/Projects/ios-client -filelist /Users/hussein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocieteGeneral-hiagtpmptjkrqjbabjxpjmnshezi/Build/Intermediates/SocieteGeneral.build/Debug-iphoneos/SocieteGeneral.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SocieteGeneral.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=5.1.1 -dead_strip -force_load -ObjC -mthumb -fobjc-arc -lsqlite3.0 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework GLKit -framework VideoToolbox -framework OpenTok -liconv -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lsqlite3 -framework LocalAuthentication /Users/hussein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocieteGeneral-hiagtpmptjkrqjbabjxpjmnshezi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreText -weak_framework AdSupport -framework CoreAudio -weak_framework Social -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework Accounts -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreVideo -framework ImageIO -framework Foundation -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework Twitter -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/hussein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocieteGeneral-hiagtpmptjkrqjbabjxpjmnshezi/Build/Intermediates/SocieteGeneral.build/Debug-iphoneos/SocieteGeneral.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SocieteGeneral_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/hussein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocieteGeneral-hiagtpmptjkrqjbabjxpjmnshezi/Build/Intermediates/SocieteGeneral.build/Debug-iphoneos/SocieteGeneral.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SocieteGeneral

ld: file not found: -ObjC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you use cocoaPods ?

Comment: i tried installing it with cocoaPods i'm still getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Ok , The problem is a bit complicated : 
when you dragged your library in your project you mess up the flags of your linker (you can see them in Build Phase -> Other Linker Flags ) , and now when cocoaPods successfully added OpenTok ( I tried it , and I had no error)  it still had the flags (with the error) . 
And now the complicated part : It is really difficult to know which flags cause problems.

(even if you delete the -Objc flags the problem can come from other flags because:
 you get some inherited ,
 your project might need this flags ,
 modifying them can create other error 
etc etc)
, and "reset" your flags can't be done in xCode.

so the best solution : is to create a new project , add with cocoapods OpenTok

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'app' do
pod 'OpenTok', '~> 2.6'
end

target 'appTests' do
pod 'OpenTok', '~> 2.6'
end

target 'appUITests' do
pod 'OpenTok', '~> 2.6'
end
```

and my bridging import :

```
#import "OpenTok/OpenTok.h"
```

to see if there is still an error in the new project with the default setting and cocoapod , and if not to drag your preccedent project files in the new project

Comment: thank you for answering but I don't think what you're suggesting is feasible. The project im trying to add it too is a huge one with multiple targets. I cannot simply drag my files in the new project!

Comment: did you save the project before add the OpenTok framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add otherLinkerFlags in Build settings

[image: Build Settings]

Try this ! And Check the deployment target make it iOS 8.0 or up .

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error due to enable bitcode. 
Try to set enable bitcode "No"

Go to Targets - > Build Settings -> Search "Enable Bitcode" -> Set to "No"

That is solved my problem.

[image: Add all frameworks said in docs as well]